Windows 10 23H2 - laptop perceptibly slower every time it's powered on
My MIL uses my old laptop for normal home office work - banking, email, taxes, online shopping, pics of grandkids - all the usual stuff. I am periodically look at this laptop as something needs to be fixed (AV sub expired, some updates are failing or simply a message pops up and MIL doesn't understand Microsoftese.
But last couple of months laptop visibly slows down. I mean - it's not a speed demon, but it was a more than adequate laptop for more resource intensive work (call center operator) four years ago, but now everything takes literally minutes - from logon, through starting firefox to opening antivirus settings (bitdefender free). I also understand that a lot of that could be linked to HDD (yes, a spinner, not a solid state, but already planning on that upgrade), however once it got into the beat, it was responsive and not that much laggy. "Quick" peek under the hood with Task Manager shows 80-90% cpu load even up to 15 min after startup. ANd, obviously it's "quick" peek because it took 2 min 15 sec for Task Manger window to show...
I am getting a distinctive Apple vibe (where they deliberately reduced battery capacity and processor clock to create appearance of phone getting worse and ready for upgrade). The computer was also last reinstalled 3 years ago, so the usual Windows fatigue can be a factor, but never have I ever seen such deterioration in such a short time...
Is it just age or Microsoft tries to shaft us?
Specs: Dell Vostro 3558 with I5-5200U and 4 GB RAM. That's more than plenty for Windows 10 Pro without any bloatware.
Diagnostics and the usual tests show no issues.
To address comments and criticisms:
Laptop is Dell Vostro 3558 with I5-5200U,4 GB RAM, 500GB HDD HGST, Integrated GPU.
Clean Windows 10 Pro 64Bit install from Microsoft, default installation, default configuration (VM file managed by system, all other settings default, all default apps that come with vanilla Windows 10 Pro).
Installed apps: Firefox (used), Chrome (not used), Bitdefender Free AV, Whatsapp, HP printer apps, MS Office.
Usage: Retired person's home office: banking via web, email via web, Word, Excel for supporting apartment-renting business, Whatsapp for grandkids' pics and vids.
This laptop was last seen by me in January, when free AV subscription had to be updated. It was NOT that dreadfully slow. Microsoft Update is working on default settings, with last batch of them installed week prior to my recent work. Since laptop was used several times, so everything should be already cached, optimized and cleaned up.

"The computer was also last reinstalled 3 years ago, so the usual Windows fatigue can be a factor, but never have I ever seen such deterioration in such a short time..." - I have had the same Windows installation for nearly 15 years, migrated across multiple devices, I receive the same performance metrics on each sequential machine as I did on day 1. Windows fatigue is almost always caused by third-party software or bad hardware.

@Ramhound - and updates to Windows, driver updates, software updates, backups and restore points... Unless you take precautions, you'd not escape bloatware completely. But. My Windows right now is "new", because I decided brand new PC deserved brand new install, but my previous windows had 6 years and was moved across 4 devices, so I know what you speak of. Laptop I speak of has Windows from Microsoft (not restore from Dell) and has maybe a dozen apps. My MIL did not add anything, as she is careful and cautious - it is a pc with banking and other stuff, after all.

You mention high CPU usage: Which applications or services are causing that high CPU usage? For comparison, I have a desktop running Windows 10 that was in-place upgraded from Windows 8 and hasn't been clean reinstalled since, and it is still running snappily. It has all OS and driver and firmware updates, and nearly all the software on it is kept up to date as well. The main things I stay on top of are making sure only necessary applications run on startup, because it is the applications that will pile up and cause slowdowns.

@AcePL - I don't believe in Windows fatigue because my system image, which is the same image after 15 years, performs identically (relative) to the original system it came from.  I don't install bad third-party software.

@Ramhound - oh. Then we speak about different things.  My previous machine hosted THE SAME INSTANCE, that I installed 6 years earlier on a different computer, and I migrated it by simply doing backup restore on the first move, then literally moving SSD from one machine to another... But that's really not the point, I also moved from high-low performance to mid-end performance, so I can't tell, and I don't care. Nevermind, then, this is off-topic.

@music2myear - what applications? Laptop is configured as a workstation with optimization for apps in the foreground, and besides the all-windows applications it has Firefox, Bitdefender, Whatsapp, Dell SupportAssist and HP printer utilities suite.... What do you think I should optimize first?

The PC, Dell Vostro 3558 with I5-5200U and 4 GB RAM, really needs more RAM for Windows. With insufficient RAM, it must swap memory to pagefile.sys and swapfile.sys on the HDD, excruciatingly slow compared to RAM speed. You can try changing the virtual memory settings, which might help -- I find setting initial and maximum VM to the same value prevents fragmentation of those files.
You can also try to reduce system load, e.g., disable unneeded services, reduce the number of background tasks (daemons in Unix parlance), increase disk space, optimize the HDD, etc., but adding RAM would likely help, too.
However, you might consider trying another OS, e.g., Linux. On an old PC, I've Ubuntu running with 2 GB RAM and using 14 GB of HDD space to hold the OS, Linux applications such as Firefox, Thunderbird, and LibreOffice suite, as well as Windows applications such as 7-Zip, IrfanView and Sumatra PDF Reader running under wine. That old machine had trouble running Windows 8.1, but is usable with Linux.
Also consider that Windows 10 will be retired October, 2025. Unless you wish to purchase extended support, in about one year, there will be no security updates.

Oh, come on. Microsoft *recommends" 4GB, but 2 GB is minimum requirements. Besides, what do you think it swaps to VM? 3 Firefox tabs? 1 Excel or Word file opened? It's not like this laptop is used for gaming. It's basic home office - most taxing stuff it must do is print documents. When I turned it on I had to wait 4 min for it to load, then next 2 min just to be able to type in username in antivirus settings window. This is not swapping issue.

@AcePL - I agree with most of this answer, in leu of, being provided specifics of the slowness. You gave no specifics on memory usage, whether or not your using a HDD or SSD. the system specifications of the interface to the system disk (NVMe, SATA, etc.). At the end of the day the system does barely meets the requirements for Windows 10.

@Ramhound - yes, I did gave specifics. Relevant to the topic. And topic is not "MY LAPTOP IS SLOW!! HELP!!" The topic is: why, in the last couple of months, this laptop slowed so much that it's not usable for most basic work. I am not the user, I am the IT guy, and I KNOW this laptop is more than sufficient to do the work. This laptop, usually, since 4 years it's being used by my mother-in-law, biggest software installs saw in the form of Microsoft updates, with the last one impacting user so much than even her saintly patience runs out.

@DrMoishePippik - no, the issue is the boot time exceeds the usual one by about 100%, and user experience with running apps is abysmal, ALL HAPPENING IN LAST COUPLE OF MONTHS. I KNOW this machine is no speed demon, but I also KNOW how this machine worked when used by one of my colleagues from then work. THis is not a random machine from the internet, it's a PC I SERVICED when it was purchased new, and I saw it in use then. And was REALLY IN USE. So why now it's unusable?

@AcePL - Hardware likely a soft failure leading to I/O errors this causing delays. Seen it before on my own system. The result of doing nothing will be that, at some point the delays will become minutes, and eventually the system will stop booting.

@Ramhound - and with it being a HDD system, it fits most of the symptoms. I actually though about it a lot. But correct me if I'm wrong: this would show as increased cpu load and hdd load simultaneously. And this is not there. HDD is showing 100%. but CPU is 8-10% or the other way around. I will swap it for SSD (or NVMe if possible - and it would be perfect, as it would then allow me to do a clone on a machine, without involving another PC), and I will also add RAM (if I have something compatible), but I feel that I will come back with "I told you so." Happy to be wrong, though.

Being rude and condescending to people helping you isn't a good course of action. I recommend that you reconsider your approach to the advice you've been offered here. 4GB is enough to run Windows, but not enough to run it quickly, and the other factors mentioned are significant also. SSD vs HDD is a VERY significant value, and you didn't include that info in the question. If you knew perfectly all these things you claim to be aware of and consider to be non-factors, you would not be coming here asking advice.

@AcePL - When it happened to me, I never saw the increased CPU load, infact most of the time I was using applications that would have a high CPU/GPU load on my system, and it was performing exactly how I would expect.  Only until I had a browser opened, and I couldn't open Task Manager for 5 minutes, then suddenly everything caught up because the I/O errors stopped or Windows gave up trying to perform the I./O action that was failing.

@music2myear - "HDD (yes, a spinner, not a solid state, but already planning on that upgrade)"... I am here for more specific advice: "I am getting a distinctive Apple vibe (where they deliberately reduced battery capacity and processor clock to create appearance of phone getting worse and ready for upgrade)(...) Is it just age or Microsoft tries to shaft us?". And "it was a more than adequate laptop for more resource intensive work (call center operator) four years ago" should give you an idea on how well I do know THIS machine, not "one like it". I will do an edit though, seems needed.

@Ramhound - "When it happened to me" I know exactly what you are talking about. In my case it was 5 months old HDD that was holding backups "only" (on a brand new machine as well). But the difference between that and the laptop in question was that I never powered down my PC since first boot (it's W11, so it updates and reboots itself, but that was some time before fail). On laptop in OP I ran diagnostics, which are [usually] picking up on such issues in tests or from SMART in advance. Not always, but often HDD gives a warning first? I had that with my HDD, but "it's new", so ignored it...

The best solution long term is, in fact, to upgrade to W11, but to do that the way it's supposed to be requires upgrading hardware - CPU, BIOS and TPM models/versions aren't supported in W11. Which, frankly, is a terrible waste, because for this user there's literally no reason to do it.
